# Angular 5, importing javascript, why does this github project only work in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, import

Below the link to the GitHub.

https://github.com/steemit/sc2-angular

When I copy paste the index.html to my angular 5 app it works. However when I move it to another component I am getting a lot of errors

```
 compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
 Can't bind to 'ng-href' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
 </button>

<a class="btn btn-primary" [ERROR ->]ng-href="{{loginURL}}" ng-hide="isAuth()">Log In</a>
  </div> "): ng:///AppModule/SteemBlogComponent.html@74:31 No provider for 
    ControlContainer ("
```

What should I change to make this work, why does index.html work on this scenario but the html file of the other components doesn't?
Has this something to do with ng-app?
I changed ng-app to reflect the new components name but still same errors.
should I fill something else in at ng-app?

Is there a way to add this javascripts as @typings.d.ts to the node_modules?
I tried it but can't get it to work.

Also if I try to add the script to the Angular-cli json file as external global script but this doesn't allow me to access the methods?

Comment: The app from GitHub is an **Angularjs** (angular 1) app which is very different from a **Angular 5** app. You cannot combine the two.

Comment: maybe if you put attention to the readme file on github you will realize that its an angularJS project, not angular!

Comment: was aware of that, however I was under the impression I could get this to work in angular 5? Should have mentioned that.

Comment: But like I said it works fine in index.html so would it be possible to make it work in the other components?